# changing default selection of ship to billing address to ship to different billing address

Tags: magento-1.9, onepage-checkout, shipping-address, billing-address

I would like to remove the `Ship to this address` from the onepage checkout and customer should type the billing address. When I browse solution for this I found few recommendation as below.

Nagivate to the function

```
public function isUseBillingAddressForShipping()
{
if (($this->getQuote()->getIsVirtual()) || !$this->getQuote()->getShippingAddress()->getSameAsBilling())
{
return false;
}
return true;
}
```

Swap around the returns “false” and “true”

```
public function isUseBillingAddressForShipping()
{
if (($this->getQuote()->getIsVirtual()) || !$this->getQuote()->getShippingAddress()->getSameAsBilling())
{
return true;
}
return false;
}
```

Is it right solution? Can I modify core file?

Comment: you need to change the shipping block to first in checkout page?

Comment: @saravanavelu No, I think that we can do core\Mage\Checkout\Block\Onepage\Abstract.php, I mean i have to force customer to type the billing address instead of giving the option as billing address is as same as shipping address

Comment: billing or shipping  address customer should enter? In billing block there is an options as ship to this address and ship to different addresses only

Comment: @saravanavelu customer should enter both. Default function is customer can mark billing address as shipping address right? That radio button should be removed. and both the section should come in default order

Comment: no customer can chose only billing as shipping by default...i.e shipping same as billing

Comment: @saravanavelu ya, that option should be removed. Customer should type both individually.